# Nine Patch Generator in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, nine-patch

I am making my first android application where I need drawables of different density like mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. So Should we use Simple Nine Patch Generator of android asset studio. Any idea ?

Here http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Comment: If you're looking for a tool that can do the job for you, try out this one:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example

Best of all, it's free and easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read this about Nine Patch http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#nine-patch

Comment: So According to that I can not right ?? then how can I get that ??

Comment: you can use nine patch when you need a background for a element and it will can change his size . a example http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-how-to-use-9-patch-png.html